Schottky Vf not matching datasheet
I am trying to set up a redundant battery power supply, two 8.4 V Li-ion batteries supplying 1 servo bus. The servos operate best at above 7 V, so I knew I needed less than 0.5 V Vf to keep the bus above 7 V even when the batteries drain down to 7.5 V during operation.
I figured a Schottky was the best route since they are made for exactly this, so I set out to find the one with the lowest Vf that would meet my amperage requirements (30 A).
I ended up with this one, which was the lowest Vf (0.4 V) at 30 A I could find.
https://www.vishay.com/docs/96462/vs-65pq015-n3.pdf
However, when I went to test one today, I am getting over 2 V drop between the batteries and the servo bus (batteries read 8.3 V, voltage at bus under 2 A load is 5.9-6.1 V.
According to the datasheet, at 2A load I should be getting m ore like 0.25 V drop.
Am I reading or not understanding the spec sheet properly?

Could you please show a picture of your setup?

How thick are your wires? How good is the contact between the wires and the components?

Are you measuring the battery voltage with the load attached or with the load removed?

Why don't you measure directly the voltage across the diode under 2A load? What is your result?

What a leaky diode ,you must keep it cool .If they used Ge would the leakage be better .These huge leakage figures are much much worse than old school Ge.

(@Autistic you must keep it cool not for leakage in this application. And regarding voltage dropped, you're better off with 85 °C  than with 25 °C. (GE may have a max. $T_j$ of 85 °C - incl. power diodes. And leakage spec'ed at 25 °C…))

@greybeard.yes for foward volts keep them warm but not too hot. But the leakage is so great that the  elxtra              power              wasted due to leakage can no longer be neglected it is watts,

Your reading of the spec sheet appears correct, so the drop may be coming from your wiring or connections.
Measure the voltage right at the diode terminals, that will eliminate wiring and connection resistance.
If the voltage there matches what the spec sheet says then measure from each battery terminal to the diodes and from the servo bus to the diodes, that should narrow down where the voltage drop is.
Also, you said you tested one today, are you connecting two batteries to the servo bus through one diode, one battery to pin 1 and one to pin 3? The datasheet shows these as a single diode with two anode pins. You can verify this by testing to see if pins 1 and 3 are shorted internally.

I believe you should be using two diodes arranged like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I have never seen it where you are supposed to combine the Anodes like in your schematic, as they are already a dual diode (two diodes in one) and combining the anodes would double the leakage. I was measuring at the Diode, and I'm using about 12" of 16g wire with clips to connect everything, using the resistance value of the wires and connectors they are only adding about 0.05v drop.
I will try paralleling the anodes but I don't think that's the issue or how they are supposed to be used.

@Ewr The datasheet shows them as a single diode, see the update to my answer. Also "clips to connect everything" sounds dodgy if you're trying to measure voltage drops at high current. The first comment asked for a picture of your setup, that would be helpful.

@Ewr could you add detail of the wire and clips to your question? What style/make are they, where did they come from, etc. Even more pertinent: what resistance do they measure? (You may need a milliohmeter setup to measure it accurately, but I have a sneaking suspicion a regular DMM will suffice here.)
